# UI Automator takes screenshots as portrait not landscape

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, ui-automation

When I take a screenshot on UIAutomator to inspect elements it is taking the screenshot as portrait when my android device is landscape and also in landscape mode. Is there a way around rotating the screenshot on UIAutomator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the screenshot in your computer. Then right click on the png image & select `Rotate right` option & save this. Again open the UIautomator & open the saved screenshot & UI XML dump & click on OK. Screenshot is displayed in landscape mode. This is how I solved this problem.